# how to use my own OkHttp client in react-native (0.54 + )

Tags: react-native, okhttp

My images and a number of other functions are sitting behind my backend APIs (written with java spark framework).  The services are https only, and APIs are often performing additional functions (eg they are not just serving static images).

In React-native javascript forms, I do

```
const imageTest='https://10.0.1.10:4567/api/v1/get-image-simple/full-size/myImage.jpg/'


            <Image source={{uri : imageTest}} 
                   style={theme.cardImageStyle}
            />
```

This does not work because my server uses self-signed certificates
(and also requires some explicit headers).

Same kinds of image urls link, work fine from within my  android host (my app is a hybrid some activities are android only, some are with react native).
My android app has custom okhttp client with all the necessary settings, to communicate to my apis via HTTPs.

I cannot find an example/reference of how to hook my OkHTTP client into react native, so that everything goes through there.
I had seen various bug reports like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13777), but cannot seem to find any documentation of what's actually in the react-native releases.

I tried, blindly, do

```
com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider.replaceOkHttpClient(
                    MyPersonalAppInstance.getApplicationComponent().okHttpClient());
```

but it does not seem to do anything;

Comment: Could I please trouble you for a full example of your custom Okhttp client? Or better yet a working repo? I am trying to increase the maximum allowed requests per hosts and not having much success so far and your issue is the closest I've gotten to a solution so far.

Comment: @Unforgiven bit time consuming to create full example for me.  However, please search for 'react-native cert pinning' examples.  It seems that multiple people are doing it. Also check https://medium.com/@jaedmuva/react-native-ssl-pinning-is-back-e317e6682642   and  https://medium.com/applike/certificate-pinning-for-mobile-android-apps-java-react-native-7dded5b6e2a4   and  https://github.com/approov/react-native-cert-pinner/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/criticalblue/reactnative/PinnedClientFactory.java

Comment: Actually, ultimately I had to build my own fork of RN from source to add this fix.

Comment: @Unforgiven there was a bug that RN team introduced in 0.61 where they apparently disabled the ability to override, but in 0.61.5 it was fixed.  I use 0.60 and overriding works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've not had a chance to test this out, but according to the discussion on `[this issue][1]`, the following should work in 0.54+ to set a custom OkHttp client.

Create React Native application and set a custom factory in the constructor, e.g.  `OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new CustomNetworkModule());`

Where a custom factory would look like:

```
class CustomNetworkModule implements OkHttpClientFactory {
    public OkHttpClient createNewNetworkModuleClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer())
                        .build();
    }
}
```

The above is based on info from [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/22efd95be1f0b236eeaaa8a8e6d01e89771c9543).

Comment: Thank you iagreen. I am getting now an error (red screen):  okhttp3.CookieJar$1 cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.modules.network.CookieJarContainer in networkingModule.java:141.   It is at least telling me that my changes are affecting something. But is there a react-native okhttp library that I should be importing instead of import okhttp3.OkHttpClient ?

Comment: @VP It looks like you need to use a react cookie jar in your custom okhttp client.  try adding `.cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer())` to your okhttpclient builder.

Comment: yes thx for updating your answer. That got me passed the error. Marked as answered.  Thank you again. Now I am trying to figure out how to copy all the interceptors and SSL stuff from my existing okhttp client into the new one (or if I can add facebook's cookie jar into mine)

Comment: For the folks, who like me already have an existing okhttp client in your host android app. Simply adding  okHttpBuilder.cookieJar(new com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer());  to your existing okhttp builder -- works.  Then I just simply accessed the okhttp client global instance and returned it from within iagreen's  createNewNetworkModule method.

Comment: You're welcome. OkHttpClient's `newBuilder` might be useful -- `reactClient = androidClient.newBuilder().setCookieJar(yourCookieJar).build` on it will take your existing client (assuming it is named `androidClient`) and copy all its settings with only changing the cookie jar.  It uses the same threads and connections under the hood, so is efficient, too.

Comment: To get all the default configuration used by react-native and build on top of that, use `OkHttpClientProvider.createClientBuilder()` instead of `new OkHttpClient.Builder()`.